# Error when I bind an Objective-C Package

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I want to bind an Objective-C Package in my Xamarin project. I follow the step from 
[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-sharpie/examples/cocoapod?context=xamarin/ios).
However,the content seems incomplete.And  I want to know what to do next.Any advice will help me.

Comment: Sorry but there's not enough details for anyone to help you. I'd suggest you add the error or log that you are getting as there could be many reasons things are not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you get two file(xxx_ApiDefinitions.cs and xxx_StructsAndEnums.cs )? Copy the code from two files to binding project.

[image]

That's not enough. The compiler will prompt a large number of errors . Such as

[image]
[image]
You have to do something. For example, use the `ulong/long` instead of `nuint` ,and annotate the  code such as `[Verify(MethodToProperty)]` .In addition,there are some differences between iOS and Xamarin.iOS in name of Object.For example ,NSURL in OC and NSUrl in C#.You need to manually modify it.

Comment: Hi,Joe. I have got two files .But I can not find the "Binding Project".

Comment: Hi,steve.You can Setup a new binding project in Visual Studio for Mac, using Add -> Add new Project … -> iOS -> Library -> Bindings Library on your existing solution

Comment: Yes,It works after I  modified more than 400 errors and warnings.You save me the da