# xamarin importing an ios framework

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm trying to get the [brother printing sdk](http://www.brother.co.jp/eng/dev/mobilesdk/download/index.aspx) working in my [Xamarin project](https://github.com/moginheden/brotherPrint) (I've got android working, but iOS sdk v3.1.9 is failing.)

I tried to use Objective Sharpie initially but what it produced is HUGE and contains lots of invalid characters and unnamed variables. (The files it produced are [here](https://github.com/moginheden/brotherPrint/tree/master/BrotherPrinterIOS/Native%20References/BRPtouchPrinterKitW.framework/Versions/Current/BRPtouchPrintKitW))

I then tried to manually create the ApiDefinition.cs and Structs.cs files, (only a few methods to start with just to see if I could get it to work at all.)

The BrotherPrintIOS project compiles, but it has a warning: "The referenced component 'Native References/BRPtouchPrinterKitW.framework' could not be found."

When I try to import the class in my PrintTest.iOS project it can't find the namespace I defined in ApiDefinitions.cs

I also had problems importing the Native References.  Since I'm compiling all this on a Windows computer running Visual Studio I had to unzip the SDK using Windows' built in "extract to" option, (I also tried 7-Zip with the same result.) When I did this it broke the link files to Headers, Resources, BRPtouchPrinterKitW, and Versions/Current. I ended up copying the files that were being referenced into the locations of the links. This seemed to let Visual Studio import the reference, but might be causing the build to not find them.

Comment: Sounds like you need to do it on a Mac, https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/340581

Comment: Here is a similar case that you can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51996644/error-when-i-bind-an-objective-c-package/51998180#51998180