# How to add Native SDK refrence to Xamarin Forms Mobile Application

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am new to xamarin forms ,i am developing xamarin forms application for cross platform(IOS,Android,UWP),when i try to integrate payment gateway to my application, my gateway provider gave the  native sdk for IOS and android,But how could i add those sdk reference to my xamarin form application.

Comment: What do you mean they gave you native sdk's? are they for Native in Xamarin? Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS? Or are they native Android and iOS

Comment: You want to bind an AAR?

Comment: i just want to use the sdk for Xamarin.IOS which is build using objective-c

Comment: This is the sdk that i want to link with my Xamarin.IOS application https://github.com/Ingenico-ePayments/connect-sdk-client-ios

Comment: does it work now  ?

Comment: @Leo thanks for response, objective Sharpie process worked fine with mac, but i would like to bind IOS library using only visual studio for windows. So for that now i am in the process of manually binding each header of objective c into c# as per the reference of "learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/bindings". But it seems to so hard because approximately the library has 150+ headers, So is there any other way for Binding IOS library with c# using visual studio 2017(Xamarin Forms) in windows?

Comment: In xamrin, I generally use NugePage ， add Native SDK,this is the only method I know. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use **Objective Sharpie** Tools to bind iOS Libraries,

refer to the official documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-objective-c/

and the solution :

[Error when I bind an Objective-C Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51996644/error-when-i-bind-an-objective-c-package/51998180#51998180)

Comment: thanks for response, objective Sharpie process worked fine with  mac,
but i would like to bind IOS library using only visual studio for windows.
So for that now i am in the process of manually binding each header of objective c into c# as per the reference of 
 "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-c-libraries?tabs=windows".
 But it seems to so hard because approximately the library has 150+ headers,
So is there any other way for Binding IOS library with c# using visual studio 2017(Xamarin Forms) in windows?