# How to use SDWebImage Binding with Xamarin,IOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, sdwebimage

I'm trying to load image from web in UIImageView in Xamarin.IOS with SDWebImage nuget but i am unable to accomplish this task

Comment: please post the relevant code and any errors or exceptions that you are getting

Comment: Sir resolved it by going for alternative FFImageLoading thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because SDWebImage is available on CocoaPod .So you can use `Objective Sharpie` to bind the library.Firstly you should download `Objective Sharpie` from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-sharpie/get-started#installing-objective-sharpie) to your mac.

Once Objective Sharpie is successfully installed, open a terminal and use the commands Objective Sharpie has to offer:

```
$ sharpie pod init -f ios SDWebImage
```

Once your CocoaPod has been set up, you can now create the binding:

```
$ sharpie pod bind
```

This will result in the CocoaPod Xcode project being built and then evaluated and parsed by Objective Sharpie. A lot of console output will be generated, but should result in the binding definition at the end just like:

```
(... lots of build output ...)

Parsing 19 header files...

Binding...
[write] ApiDefinitions.cs
[write] StructsAndEnums.cs

Done.
```

However ,there are some errors in  ApiDefinitions.cs and StructsAndEnums.cs.Here is a [similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51996644/error-when-i-bind-an-objective-c-package/51998180#51998180) that you can refer .

By addition ,if you want to load image ,you can use [FFImageLoading](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.FFImageLoading/2.4.5.860-pre).

Comment: While Executing "sharpie pod init ios SDWebImage" it says "error: invalid SDK identifier: ios"

Comment: Sir Still the same problem

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-sharpie/examples/cocoapod?context=xamarin/mac

Comment: I think its better for me to go for FFImageLoading Library , I am marking your answer as right

Comment: Ok,happy coding:)