# CFNetwork reference is missing while creating IOS Binding project using Objective Sharpie

Tags: objective-c, xamarin.ios, objective-sharpie

I would like to use TriPos IOS mobile payment gateway,i have downloaded the IOS sdk from official site "https://developer.vantiv.com/servlet/JiveServlet/download/1915-27-5158/iOS+Release+v1.4.0+triPOS+Mobile+SDK.zip".Since  that is a objective C library i cannot use that directly into my Xamarion.IOS project.I have created the binding project with the help of Objective sharpie tool using command "sharpie bind /Users/kmit/Desktop/tripossdk/triPOSMobileSDK.framework/Headers/ triPOSMobileSDK.h -sdk iphoneos12.1",it generate Apidefinition.cs and StructAndEnum.cs file with huge Error.I have solved may of the error based on the reference "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-objective-c/walkthrough?tabs=windows#create-a-xamarinios-binding-project". but seems like objective sharpie missed to add CFNetwork reference so i am getting reference Error for that ,so am i missed anything ?

I have also tried to include CFNetwork as dll reference but cannot able to find any referencable dll.

[Error Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJzTY.jpg)

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51996644/error-when-i-bind-an-objective-c-package.

Comment: thanks for reply,actually i have solved all the errors mentioned over there.My case is my binding library contains reference to CFNetwork so objective sharpie generate code with using CFNetwork. but i couldn't get referenced dll.i have added snapshot of error above.